# How to create a multi-dimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to populate data for markers on map. I can get it to work using static content but I would like to set sites content by reading from an array.

```
var sites = [
  ['User 1', 45.4210328, -75.6900218, 4],
  ['User 2', 40.315939, -105.440630,  2],
  ['User 3', 43.785890, -101.90175,   1],
  ['User 4', 39.99948,  -105.28370,   3]
];   

setMarkers(map, sites);
```

I tried this

```
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)
{
    var sites = [
                    [arr[i].username, arr[i].latitude, arr[i].longitude, i
                ];
}
```

but as a result `sites` only contain one array i.e. the last array. Not all the arrays. How can I create multi-dimensional array within `sites`?

Comment: as a side note: your code now contains a syntax error (extra `[` or missing `]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sites = [];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)
{     
   sites.push([arr[i].username, arr[i].latitude, arr[i].longitude, i]);
}
```